# How to fix DIV height when resizing width? Mobile/Table/PC browser compatible

Tags: css, resize, height, width, percentage

I have a trouble about % width and height:
I would like to give every sizes in percentages (mobile, tablet, pc browser, etc. compatibility) but when I resize the browser WIDTH that causes the HEIGHT to be resized too FOR ALL ELEMENTS. How to stop height modifying when height isn't changed? I just want the height to fit to the elements' content and no more.

My site structure:

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
}

html, body{
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0% auto 0%;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 overflow: auto;
}

.headline, .menu, .content{
 display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
 width: 58%;
 font-size: 90%;
 margin: 1% auto 0%;
 padding: 1%;
 text-align: left;
}

.innerDiv{
 width: 98%;
 padding: 1%;
 margin: 0% auto 1%;
        text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
<DIV id='wrapper'>
  <DIV class='headline'>
    Headline content and divs.
  </DIV>
  <DIV class='menu'>
    Menu elements: divs, inputs.
  </DIV>
  <DIV class='content'>
    <DIV class='innerDiv'>
      A line for one question and one answer (div+input).
    </DIV>
    <DIV class='innerDiv'>
      One more line for another question and answer.
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Have you thought of using a responsive framework like Bootstrap

Comment: No I have not thought about yet. But @fcastillo 's answer above solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any percentile value is relative to the size of the viewport. Viewport Height (VH) and Viewport Width (VW) are also relative. If you want to ensure your elements are always the same size, use an EM value.

Comment: Well. This is the best way at the moment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vw` and `vh`units that are based on width and height of viewport. [CSS units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bnwynhfu/1/)

Comment: Good option but at the moment i tried the em as @Dan suggested and works very well :)
Thank you very much!